# How to have multiple landscape views in Xcode 4.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, orientation, landscape

Ok, so I want to have 3 view and all of them landscape but i want 2 of the to be in ONLY landscape and i want ONLY 1 OF THEM to be in portrait. When i do this they all go in portrait.  I am using storyboards.

I have in the .m file:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}
```

I have it set up to landscape left in the target and in the plist, I have "Initial interface orientation" and "supported orientations landscape left". I have tried everything and nothing has worked, someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);

}
```

Add this to each view controller which you want to have in landscape mode. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am using storyboard how should i do that?

Comment: How the scene is actually displayed is not determined by the storyboard but rather the viewcontroller. You need to create an UIViewController subclass and implement - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation as above which return YES only if the interface orientation is a landscape orientation.